# Bound on function of sum of powers

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-game-theory, multinomial-coefficients

Let $(x_1, \ldots, x_k)\in R^k$ and $n=n_1+\ldots +n_k$, with $n\in N_0$ and $0\leq n_i\leq n$
Consider function $M_n=\sum_{i=1, \textit{number of terms is $2\ell+1$}}^kx_i^{n_i}$-function with odd number of terms.

Find the lower bound of $M_n$.

Comment: Isolated problems are [discouraged](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) here. A little bit of context (why do you need it, and what kind of? what are your own thoughts?) would definitely improve the question.